# Running tflite model on react native-expo android

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, expo, tensorflow-lite

I have a tfjs and tflite custom image classification model that I want to run on my Expo managed react native project
After a lot of research I found a library [react native tflite fast](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-tflite) but it only works on IOS. I can use the tfjs model but really wanted to use the tflite model so does anyone have experience with this problem